# Finding Closing XML tag

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax, stax

I have an method to print out just the contents between an opening and closing XML tag. I know my XML depth counter is the issue, but I can't figure out where to put it / fix it. Here is the XML.

```
<XMS>
    <Object>
        <Property>
            <Value>1</Value>
        </Property>
    </Object>
</XMS>
```

Here is the Java code...

```
    Boolean flag = false;

    while(reader.hasNext()) {
        eventType = reader.next();

        if(getEventType(eventType) == "START_ELEMENT" 
                && reader.getLocalName() == startTagName){
            flag = true;
            depth++;
            System.out.println(reader.getLocalName() + " Depth = " + depth);
        }
        else if(getEventType(eventType) == "END_ELEMENT"
                && flag == true
                && (depth == 0)){
            depth--;
            System.out.println(reader.getLocalName() + " Depth = " + depth + " BIG END");
            break;
        }
        else if(getEventType(eventType) == "START_ELEMENT"
                && flag == true){
            depth++;
            System.out.println(reader.getLocalName() + " Depth = " + depth);
        }
        else if(getEventType(eventType)== "END_ELEMENT"
                && flag == true){
            depth--;
            System.out.println(reader.getLocalName() + " Depth = " + depth + " END");
        }
    }
}
```

GetEventType simply returns the proper eventType (works properly). And here's the output from, the console.

```
Object Depth = 1
Property Depth = 2
Value Depth = 3
Value Depth = 2 END
Property Depth = 1 END
Object Depth = 0 END
XMS Depth = -1 BIG END
```

The issue is it should end on the last object when depth = 0 and stop before getting to XMS depth = -1. Any Advice?

Comment: Have you find your awnser?

Answer (score 1):

could it be as simple as comparing if depth is equal to one instead of zero?

when you're within the "Object" element, your depth == 1, hence when you encounter the ending "Object" tag you should be checking

```
   ... && (depth == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

EventType is an `int` not a String, you are comparing with the wrong values.  Also, you do not compare Strings in java using `==`, you use `equals()`.  also, flag should be a `boolean` (primitive).

as a future note, when confronted with issues like this, learn to run your code in a debugger in order to find your logic problems, not post on SO.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention I have a method that transforms the int into a string to compare (getEventType(eventType)). I do need to fix the == vs. equals() however if that weren't working it wouldn't give me any output at all.

Comment: Always compare Strings with `.equals()`

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
    else if(getEventType(eventType) == "END_ELEMENT"
                    && flag == true
                    && (depth == 0)){
                depth--;
//rest of your code
```

Your if condition have `(depth == 0)` as one of the condition and in your method body you're doing `depth--;`. Wouldn't that decrement depth to -1 ?

My question is: do you really need to do  `depth--;` if you have  `if (depth == 0)` ?